# Can't resolve 'util' in 'node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src'

Tags: google-translate, google-translate-api

I'm trying to implement the google translate api and am encountering this error when I import the Translate function. I have followed the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/translate/latest). This is my code:

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
```